# How to change checkbox status based on certain value, and how to post a list of checkboxes back tot server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a Group  Users Assignment module.
For this I have two models:

1. `Group` . Store Group Info.
2. `UserGroup`. Store the info about the associate between Group and user (`UserID`, `GroupID`).
3. I do not have a table for users, since they are AD users.

First of all I wrote the following `Action Method`:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id) {   
    ViewBag.ADUsers =   repository.GetADUsers();
    return View(repository.FindAllGroup(id));
}
```

Where the `repository.GetADUsers` will retrieve all users, currently inside Active Directory.
The view is as follow:

```
@model TMS.Models.Group

<h2> Assign Users To the Group</h2>
@foreach (var ad in ViewBag.ADUsers) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div >@ad.SamAccountName </div>
        </td>
    </tr> 
}
```

But how I can expand this to include these main features.

1. Currently I am displaying a list of all AD user. But I need to add a `CheckBox` beside the `SamAccoutnName`.
2. If the `SamAccountName` is already assigned to the `Group`, then the `CheckBox` should be `checked = true`, otherwise it should be `checked = false`.
3. To add a AssignUsersGroup Post action method, that will accept the list of `CheckBox` es and update the `UserGroup` table accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer 1 and 2, but not 3.

> 1. Currently I am displaying a list of all AD user. But I need to add a CheckBox beside the SamAccoutnName.
> 2. If the SamAccountName is already assigned to the Group, then the CheckBox should be checked = true, otherwise it should be checked =
>      false.

You just need to add the HTML for a checkbox into your foreach, and then use an if statement to check for your "checked" condition:

```
@foreach (var ad in ViewBag.ADUsers) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if (ad.isInGroup) 
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="@ad.SamAccountName" checked="checked">
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="@ad.SamAccountName" checked="">
            }
            <div >@ad.SamAccountName </div>
        </td>
    </tr> 
}
```

You  probably want to change that `<div>` to a span`<span>` if you want those items to be side-by-side.

Also, my example assumes your "ad" object has a property that indicates whether the person is in this group or not.  You need to use whatever method you're currently using to check that.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<TypeOfListReturn> ADUsersList = ViewBag.ADUsers as List<TypeOfListReturn>;

foreach (var ad in ADUsersList )
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                @ad.SamAccountName
                @Html.CheckBox("chk_" + ad.SamAccountName, ad.isInGroup)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

This is answer for your 1 and 2nd.
For the third i would prefer you to use model. If you use model to bind the name and the check box then in post back the value of the check box will be returned.